How can I search for messages in Slack channels that follow a certain pattern?
E.g., I have 3 Slack channels:

#hello-blue-world
#test-blue-case
#this-blue

I have other Slack channels that don't contain blue in their names.
How can I search for messages in Slack channels that contain blue in their names?
I tried searching for test in:#*blue*, where test is the word I am looking for in channels named *blue*, it didn't work.
